# SmartOS configuring zone networking issue - no connectivity

Tags: networking, solaris, smartos

I am experimenting a bit with SmartOS on a spare dedicated server.
I have 2 IP adresses on the server.
for ex 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 (They are not in the same range).

The global zone was configured my global zone to use the IP 1.1.1.1

Here is the configuration of my global zone

```
[root@global ~]# dladm show-link
LINK        CLASS     MTU    STATE    BRIDGE     OVER
igb0        phys      1500   up       --         --
igb1        phys      1500   up       --         --
net0        vnic      1500   ?        --         igb0
[root@global ~]# dladm show-phys
LINK         MEDIA                STATE      SPEED  DUPLEX    DEVICE
igb0         Ethernet             up         1000   full      igb0
igb1         Ethernet             up         1000   full      igb1
[root@global ~]# ifconfig
lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
igb0: flags=1004843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DHCP,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet 1.1.1.1 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 1.1.1.255
        ether c:c4:7a:2:xx:xx
igb1: flags=1000842<BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 3
        inet 0.0.0.0 netmask 0
        ether c:c4:7a:2:xx:xx
lo0: flags=2002000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv6,VIRTUAL> mtu 8252 index 1
        inet6 ::1/128
```

I configured my zone the following way

```
[root@global ~]# vmadm get 84c201d4-806c-4677-97f9-bc6da7ad9375 | json nics
[
  {
    "interface": "net0",
    "mac": "02:00:00:78:xx:xx",
    "nic_tag": "admin",
    "gateway": "2.2.2.254",
    "ip": "2.2.2.2",
    "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
    "primary": true
  }
]
[root@84c201d4-806c-4677-97f9-bc6da7ad9375 ~]# ifconfig
lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
net0: flags=40001000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,L3PROTECT> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet 2.2.2.2 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 2.2.2.255
        ether 2:0:0:78:xx:xx
lo0: flags=2002000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv6,VIRTUAL> mtu 8252 index 1
        inet6 ::1/128
[root@84c201d4-806c-4677-97f9-bc6da7ad9375 ~]# dladm show-link
LINK        CLASS     MTU    STATE    BRIDGE     OVER
net0        vnic      1500   up       --         ?
[root@84c201d4-806c-4677-97f9-bc6da7ad9375 ~]# netstat -rn

Routing Table: IPv4
Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref     Use     Interface
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ---------- ---------
default              87.98.252.254        UG        2         47 net0
87.98.252.0          87.98.252.162        U         4         23 net0
127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1            UH        2          0 lo0
```

However i have no connectivity to the internet in my zone.
Is there anything misconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you want to bypass your second real IP to guest zone. 
According to [wiki](http://wiki.smartos.org/display/DOC/extra+configuration+options#extraconfigurationoptions-AdditionalNICs) you should configure tag for second NIC (igb1) and use it in your guest zone.